# What percentage of a disk is reserved (can not be used)

Tags: disk, diskspace

I want to know what percentage of a disk is always reserved (which can not be used or written), I need this information to know if I can write a file on the disk with a certain size.
For example, if I have 100MB total and 1% is reserved then I should at least have 2MB available in free space to write a 1MB file.

consider the given df command SS
[df -h](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Za7j.png)

here mnt/C is shown 100% full but it still has 13GB available and if I try to write something on this drive then I can not. So I assume this is reserved space.

But I need the value of exactly what % space is reserved so that I can generate a formula.

Comment: This is not a programming question. In any case, it depends on the OS and perhaps other environmental factors.

Comment: `df` shows the space that is available. The reserved part is in the % used (try it with an empty disk). There may be other reasons why you cannot write to the disk. Anyway, the reserved part depends on the type of file system used and the parameterisation of that filesystem.